# Excel Autofill Linegraph with Time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, temperature

I must admit that I am not the expert on excel, but I need help creating a graph with some data.  In column A, I have over 500 cells filled with temperature values from a probe.  Now, technically each data point is five minutes away from the other, so A1's temp reading was taken at zero minutes, and A2's temp reading was taken at five minutes, A3 at 10 min and so on.

I would like to be able to populate column B with the time in minutes, and then plot a line graph with the temperature values over time.  I do not want to have to enter in the times manually, because I would have to fill in over 500 cells by hand.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward enough.

Firstly I would move all your readings to Column B as it will look better on your graph.

Then in A1 put in: 00:00

Then in A2 put in: 00:05

Next highlight A1 and A2, and a black square dot will appear in the bottom right of A2, drag that down as far as you want it to go, The time will increment by 5min.